# How to change Google Chart API inside Flask-appbuilder?

Tags: flask-appbuilder

Since Goolge Chart API is not available inside China. I want to replace it with Baidu's ECharts.

Should I define another ChartView, and is there any official document on How To?

Right now, I am using Jinja2 template to include echarts.js (lib) and custom js code (action) as well as custom method in view (data source) at the end of the html file. But I hope there is official way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty and quick solution, I use another template with custom js code for Baidu's ECharts.

In next plan, I will override FAB design.